# Localization not working after changing .NET core project target framework from .NetCoreApp 1.0 to 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

Localization in my not .NET core project stopped working after changing target framework from .NetCoreApp 1.0 to 1.1 (nothing else was modified), here is the application startup code. I use a custom culture provider, so I verified that it returns correct cultures.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<MyAppOptions>(Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options
            .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(CoreEventId.IncludeIgnoredWarning))
            .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning)));

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(Security.TeamAdmin, policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, Security.TeamAdmin));
            options.AddPolicy(Security.SuperAdmin, policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, Security.SuperAdmin));
        });

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver())
            .AddViewLocalization(
                LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.SubFolder,
                options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
            options.SupportedCultures = TeamConfig.SupportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = TeamConfig.SupportedCultures;
            options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new MyCultureProvider(options.DefaultRequestCulture));
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseTeamDatabaseSelector();
        app.UseTeamAuthentication();

        var localizationOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions.Value);

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "modules",
                template: "m/{ModuleName}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Modules", action = "Index" }
                );
        });
    }
}
```